# Can't return correct reference from db.ref('reference').orderByChild('child').equalTo('value').ref;

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to grab the reference of a query result, however all I'm getting a reference to is the original key. For example;

```
const reference = db.ref('reference').orderByChild('child').equalTo('value').ref;
```

My reference variable seems to be pointing towards the node 'reference' and not the result of my query. Is this correct behaviour as the documents only mention that equalTo returns a reference, which I've assumed is to the result of the query?

Is there any alternative way of grabbing a reference to a query result?

Comment: Can you, please, give more details on how do you want to user the `reference` variable?

Answer (score 2):

The `.ref` at the end of your query returns the original reference on which you're running the query. So these two lines have the exact same result:

```
const reference = db.ref('reference').orderByChild('child').equalTo('value').ref;
const reference = db.ref('reference');
```

To keep the actual query, use:

```
const reference = db.ref('reference').orderByChild('child').equalTo('value');
```